# .npmrc failed to replace env in config

Tags: bash, zsh, zshrc, npmrc

Me and my colleagues have a problem with .npmrc

Most of us are on Mac OSx and this works

`@REGISTRY_NANME:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/ //gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`

But for me it don't work, but without `{}` like below, it works for me
`@REGISTRY_NANME:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/ //gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN`

What could cause that? How can I have the same behaviour than my colleagues?

I tried with zsh and .zhsrc, with bash and .bash_profile too.

I tried with npm and yarn

Using quoted and unquoted `export NPM_TOKEN="<token>"`

Tried to remove the `{}` in my .npmrc

Tried with a .yarnrc file

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe unlike your colleagues you have some special characters in your NPM_TOKEN variable?

Comment: Does hyphens are a special character??

Comment: Try to generate a new NPM_TOKEN without hyphens and test it.